# Determining HTML5 compatibility

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Is there ASP.NET Razor code that I can use to determine if someone is browsing my site using an HTML5 compatible browser? Or if not Razor, maybe JavaScript or even server side C# code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as an "HTML5 Compatible Browser." HTML5 consists of a lot of features, most of which have a (Javascript) way to detect that they are available and working.

[Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) is a useful tool to help you determine which features are available. There are others out there, and it's not hard to roll your own for specific features.

Comment: True. I do not want EVERY single HTML5 feature. Specifically, I just need to detect if the browser supports HTML5 canvas features and HTML5 Web SQL. If the browser doesn't support this, then i was hoping to be able to redirect them to a page that used a Java applet instead.

Comment: For canvas, the test is `return !!document.createElement('canvas').getContext;` (snagged from http://diveintohtml5.org/detect.html). I believe Web SQL is a non-standard standard, and you are supposed to use `localStorage` instead.

Comment: Yeah I saw that canvas test. I will use that. As far as Web SQL, I might just drop that all together and go with SQL Server instead.

Answer (score 0):

you could try [HttpBrowserCapabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yekbd5b.aspx#Y300)
it offers some informations about the browser, not sure if it offers the version oh HTML supported... but you could give it a try...

or you can store in DB compatible browsers and check every time...

Comment: I saw this, but I didn't see any specific properties for determining HTML5

Comment: check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875951/asp-net-how-to-check-browser-support-html5

and this article http://diveintohtml5.org/detect.html