# How do i check whether the browser supports HTML5 using c#.net

Tags: c#, javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET - How to check browser support html5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875951/asp-net-how-to-check-browser-support-html5)

Is there any possible solution in .NET to check whether the browser is supporting the HTML 5?

Thanks

Comment: try this:
[ASP.NET - How to check browser support html5?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875951/asp-net-how-to-check-browser-support-html5

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Dive Into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/) , it is client side stuff, has nothing to do with .net or c#.

OR if you really want to read it in server side, you can read the `UserAgent` Header from the request, and determine whether it support HTML5 or not from it.

Answer (score 0):

please check this link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh335062.aspx
Modernizr - JS library to use new features but keep backwards compatibility; - provides semantic markup, feature detection for major HTML5 technologies and support for conditional CSS based on supported features.

I think you want to check the client browser supporting HTML 5 or not and based on that you want to write the code dynamically. If my assumption is right, then above solution will solve your problem.

Comment: please go through this link also   http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2011/09/01/pfcov_HTML5.aspx